# Partial View not bringing in ApplicationUser data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax and rendering a Partial View. The data is being passed fine into the controller. There is nothing null. However for some reason in my Partial View the OwnerUser and the AssignToUser are null but the Hours and the Body are coming through with the correct information. I have this same implementation in another part of my project and it's working fine, even with the user coming in. I can't figure out why in this Partial View the ApplicationUser data is null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChatAjax([Bind(Include = "Body")] Chat chat, string   ChatData)
    {
        chat.Created = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        chat.OwnerUserId = user;
        chat.AssignToUserId = ChatData;
        db.Chats.Add(chat);

        db.SaveChanges();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Chats", chat);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("LandingPage", "Admin");
    }
```

This is my Partial View:

```
 @model BugTracker.Models.Chat

@{    
  var day = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset.Hours;
 }

<div class="direct-chat-msg">
  <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
     <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left"> 
         @Model.OwnerUser.FirstName</span>
     <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right"> 
          @Model.Created.AddHours(day)
     </span>
     <br />
     <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">Sent to 
          @Model.AssignToUser.DisplayName 
     </span>
  </div>
  <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
  <div class="direct-chat-text" style="background:lightblue">
       @Model.Body
  </div>
 <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
</div>
```

Here is my Chat Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BugTracker.Models
{
   public class Chat
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public string OwnerUserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Assign")]
    public string AssignToUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser OwnerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AssignToUser { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you assigning values to the `OwnerUserId` and `AssignToUserId` but are those different from `OwnerUser` and `AssignToUser`?

Comment: Can you provide the `Chat` model?

Comment: From the OwnerUserId and AssignToUserId you extract the name from it because all the information is brought over when you assign them.